# Convert python dictionary to dataframe with dict values(list) as columns and 1,0 if that column is in dict list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to create a dataframe from a dictionary which is of the format

```
Dictionary_ =  {'Key1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'Key2': ['d', 'f'],'Key3': ['a', 'c', 'm', 'n']}
```

I am using

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dictionary_, orient ='index')
```

But it creates its own columns till max length of values and put values of dictionary as values in a dataframe.

I want a df with keys as rows and values as columns like

```
       a     b      c     d     e     f    m     n 
Key 1  1      1      1    1     0    0    0     0
Key 2  0      0      0    1     0    1    0     0
Key 3  1      0      1    0     0    0    1     1
```

I can do it by appending all values of dict and create an empty dataframe with dict keys as rows and values as columns and then iterating over each row to fetch values from dict  and put 1 where it matches with column,  but this will be too slow as my data has 200 000 rows and   .loc is slow.  I feel i can use pandas dummies somehow  but don't know how to apply it here.

I feel there will be a smarter way to do this.

Comment: Thank you anky for editing the question in right format,  this is my first question so i didn't know how to do it correctly. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, in your free time you can go through this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Sure,  i will :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is important, use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and pass `keys` and `values`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(Dictionary_.values()),
                  columns=mlb.classes_, 
                  index=Dictionary_.keys()))
print (df)
      a  b  c  d  f  m  n
Key1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
Key2  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
Key3  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
```

Alternative, but slowier is create `Series`, then [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) for `string`s and last call [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.Series(Dictionary_).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
print (df)
      a  b  c  d  f  m  n
Key1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
Key2  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
Key3  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
```

Alternative with input `DataFrame` - use [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but then is necessary aggregate `max` per columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dictionary_, orient ='index')

df = pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
      a  d  b  c  f  m  n
Key1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
Key2  0  1  0  0  1  0  0
Key3  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_dummies`:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df).rename(columns=lambda x: x[2:]).max(axis=1, level=0)
      a  d  b  c  f  m  n
Key1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
Key2  0  1  0  0  1  0  0
Key3  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
>>>
```